# $.post NOT working in live server

Tags: jquery, json, .post

I have a html file that uses the following script...

```
<script>
      $(function () {
            $('#members-table').bootstrapTable({ 
            }).on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
               var myJsonString = "["+JSON.stringify(row)+"]";
              // alert(myJsonString);
               $.post("save-id.php",{
                    data: myJsonString,
                   });
            });
    });`enter code here`  
</script>
```

it calls the save-id.php file which goes as follows...

```
<?php
session_start();
$row = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
foreach($row as $value) { 
     $memberID = $value['memberID']; 
     break;
    }
    $_SESSION["memberID"] = $memberID;
?>
```

Now this thing works fine when I run it on localhost (using XAMPP) but when I uploaded this to a live server (000WebHost), the php file is not receiving any data.

Comment: do you get any sort of error / info from the console or XHR network connection when the post is made to save-id.php?  For me, I always use chromes dev tool to monitor the post attempt, inspect the headers, etc and to see if any error is returned in the response that gives me a clue why its not working.  Also try using save-id.php as a a test using query string variables to see if it works alone, just as a means of eliminating it as the culprit... you'd have to change _POST to _GET though.

Comment: I tried this now... I got the following message in the preview window **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**  which is strange because this works perfectly on my local server

Comment: maybe a difference in the PHP versions?  PHPinfo should tell you what version each (your local server vs. live server) are running.

Comment: I compared the PHPinfo for both the servers. In the local server the _POST["data"] has Json data but in the live server _POST["data"] is filled with slashes (\), escaping " most probably. Should I try using stripslashes()

Comment: great, wish I would have posted as an answer instead of a comment so could get credit!  Glad to help.

Comment: you could still post it as an answer.... it really helped me understand the importance of using "stripslashes()"

Comment: awesome, just added the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trouble shoot, do you get any sort of error / info from the console or XHR network connection when the post is made to save-id.php? For me, I always use chromes dev tool to monitor the post attempt, inspect the headers, etc and to see if any error is returned in the response that gives me a clue why its not working. Also try using save-id.php as a a test using query string variables to see if it works alone, just as a means of eliminating it as the culprit... you'd have to change _POST to _GET though.

...maybe a difference in the PHP versions? PHPinfo should tell you what version each (your local server vs. live server) are running?